# ngOnInit visibility of private member

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, ngoninit

I have the following Directive.

From within ngOnInit, both this.word and this.components are "undefined".

Could anyone explain me why?

```
import { Directive , Input, Output, ViewContainerRef, ComponentRef, DynamicComponentLoader, EventEmitter, OnInit, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Widget } from '../widget.model';
import { CommentComponent } from './comment.component';


@Directive({selector: 'widget-factory'})
export class WidgetFactory {
  @Input() name: any;
  @Input() id: Number;

  @Output() loaded = new EventEmitter();

  private components: { 'Comment': CommentComponent };
  private word: "hello";

  constructor(
    private _dcl: DynamicComponentLoader,
    private _elementRef: ViewContainerRef
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Get the current element 
    console.log(this.word);
    let component: any;
    //if(this[name] === 'Comment') {
      component = CommentComponent
    //}
    this._dcl.loadNextToLocation(CommentComponent, this._elementRef);
    console.log(this.name);

  }
}
```

Heavily inspired by this:     [Outputting array of components in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562626/outputting-array-of-components-in-angular-2/35567656)

Comment: There is no reason that `this.word` etc. would not be visible within `ngOnInit()`. Their `private` nature is merely a compile-time concept that has no effect on the way the code works. There must be something else going on that we're not seeing. by the way, where is `Comment` defined? As your code stands, this is unlikely to compile, and if you run it anyway, you'll get a `ReferenceError` when `components` is initialized.

Comment: Where is Comment defined? Thanks for the question, this is actually a mistake. It should be CommentComponent and CommentComponent is a Component. And it solved my problem.

However, I still don't see the variable this.word within the class

Comment: I updated the code

Answer (score 2):

```
private word: "hello";
```

This defines a field named "word", whose **type** is "hello". I.e. the only valid value (except for undefined and null) it can have is "hello". It doesn't initialize the field, so it's still undefined. If you want a field of type string, initialized to "hello", you need

```
private word = "hello";
```

which is a shorter form (thanks to type inference) for

```
private word: string = "hello";
```

The same explanation stands for `components`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is pretty simple, you just confused the assignment of `type` and `value`.

Now you have:    `private word: "hello";`

Should be:   `private word: string = "hello";`

After `:` goes type, then default value after `=`.

`access_modificatior variable_name: type = default_value`