# Use a component as element - Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-components

I would like to use a component as an item. 
Instead of using:

```
<ul class='biblList'>
    <li *ngFor="let biblCit of biblCits">
        {{ biblCit }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to use something like:

```
<evt-bibliography-item *ngFor="let biblCit of biblCits">
    {{ biblCit }}
</evt-bibliography-item>
```

Being a novice with angular I don't know how to figure it out.

Comment: What did you already tried?

Comment: I tried creating an empty component and calling it with a tag, but it is clearly incomplete code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562626/outputting-array-of-components-in-angular-2/35567656

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use  `<ng-content></ng-content>` at the component template and this will project the template from the parent

*bibliography component template*

```
<div>
<ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

parent

```
<app-bibliography *ngFor="let biblCit of biblCits">
         {{ biblCit }} 
</app-bibliography>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxyhyr)

Comment: @downvoter what's reason to downvote? It would be really helpful to improve my reply

Comment: For me it was the right solution! I had to read between the lines, but in the end I realized it was what I was looking for!

Comment: @Memmo  happy to hear that my answer solve your problem , thanks 

Answer (score 1):

here is [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-k9jfxv?file=app/app.component.ts)

.ts

```
biblCits=['1','2','2','3','4','5']
```

.html

```
<div *ngFor="let biblCit of biblCits">
    <child-component [parentTimerCount]="biblCit">
    </child-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use iterator `*ngFor` to iterate through components:

```
<ng-content *ngFor="let biblCit of biblCits">
  <evt-bibliography-item></evt-bibliography-item>
</ng-content>
```

Comment: @downvoter what's reason to downvote? It would be really helpful to improve my reply

Comment: `evt-bibliography-item` is not a known element

Comment: @Memmo it looks like you've not imported your component.

Comment: in `app.module` or elsewhere?

Comment: if it is standalone component, then yeah, import into `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<ng-content></ng-content>` inside of your `evt-bibliography-item` component's template to access everything passed between your own component tags, in your case the value of `{{ biblCit }}`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'evt-bibliography-item',
    template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class BibliographyItem {
}
```